# Displaying a date in php 24 hours later, issues

Tags: php

I'm basically trying to add 24 hours to a date with php and display it but it keeps adding only 23 hours in stead of 24 hours.

```
<?php
    $create_time = strtotime('2015-03-18 20:03:23');
    $set_time = $create_time + 3600*24;
    echo gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $set_time);
?>
```

So the result that I'm getting out of this is:

**2015-03-19 19:03:23**

but it's this what should be coming out of this:

**2015-03-19 20:03:23**

I'm new at working with these time functions and I can't figure out why it keeps getting adding 23 hours. Obviously I can multiply it by 25 and get 24 hours but that doesn't make sense to me.

So my question is: what's the proper way to add 24 hours to a date?

Comment: You do realise that not every day has 24 hours? (at least in most countries of the world).... typically it's called daylight savings

Comment: However, you're specifically using GMT in one statement, but the default timezone in another.... which can easily lead to differences if your system default timezone isn't GMT

Comment: Might be a time zone issue. Remember that gmdate also converts it to GMT, so if your system time zone is not GMT then it won't come out as you are hoping. See my answer below.

Comment: Quoting from the PHP docs for strtotime(): `Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter.`

Comment: You'll also find handling timezones and daylight savings is a whole lot easier if you use [DateTime objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: Thanks guys, you were right I should've been using date() instead of gmdate()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like so:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 day"));
```

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime()` uses default time zone, `gmdate()` uses Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). Try using `date()` instead.

```
<?php
    $create_time = strtotime('2015-03-18 20:03:23');
    $set_time = $create_time + 3600*24;
    echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $set_time);
?>
```